# Abstract over repeated flatMap

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am trying to generalize repeated, nested `flatMap` but not sure if one exists.

The following code will produce all combinations of *n choose 3*, [image: n choose 3]:

```scala
def choose3flatMap(n: Int, r: Int = 3) =
  (0 to n - r)
    .flatMap(i => (i + 1 to n - (r - 1))
      .flatMap(j => (j + 1 to n - (r - 2))
        .map(k => Seq(i, j, k))))
```

Repeating the flatMap operation, we can get all combinations of *n choose 5*, [image: n choose 5] :

```scala
def choose5flatMap(n: Int, r: Int = 5) =
  (0 to n - r)
    .flatMap(i => (i + 1 to n - (r - 1))
      .flatMap(j => (j + 1 to n - (r - 2))
        .flatMap(k => (k + 1 to n - (r - 3))
          .flatMap(l => (l + 1 to n - (r - 4))
            .map(m => Seq(i, j, k, l, m)))))
```

Clearly there is a pattern here.  I would like to utilize this similarity to get a general solution for *n choose r*, [image: n choose r].  Is there a simple way to accomplish this.  Perhaps a higher order function of some sort?

#### What I have tried:

Scala lets me rewrite the `map`/`flatMap` with a for expression.  This reads cleaner, but the number of choices in still hard-coded.

```scala
def choose3Loop(n: Int, r: Int = 3) =
  for {
    i <- 0 to n - r
    j <- i + 1 to n - (r - 1)
    k <- j + 1 to n - (r - 2)
  } yield Seq(i, j, k)
```

I can write a recursive solution directly using `flatMap` or utilizing the sugar of a `for` expression:

```scala
def combinationsRecursive(n: Int, r: Int, i: Int = 0): Seq[Seq[Int]] =
  if (r == 1) (i until n).map(Seq(_))
  else {
    (i to n - r).flatMap(
      i => combinationsRecursive(n, r - 1, i + 1).map(j => i +: j))
  }

def combinationsRecursiveLoop(n: Int, r: Int, i: Int = 0): Seq[Seq[Int]] =
  if (r == 1) (i until n).map(Seq(_))
  else
    for {
      i <- i to n - r
      j <- combinationsRecursiveLoop(n, r - 1, i + 1)
    } yield i +: j
```

While these are solutions to the general problem, I wonder if there is a higher-level abstraction I am missing here that may be applicable to other problems as well.  I recognize that for this particular application, I could do `(0 to n).combinations(r)` to use a library-provided implementation of computing combinations.

While the above code is Scala, in this case I am interested the functional programming aspect of it and not the language capabilities.  If there is a solution but one that is not supported by Scala I am interested in that.

**Edit:**  He is a sample caller and the resulting output by request:

> scala> combinationsRecursiveLoop(5, 3)
>
> res0: Seq[Seq[Int]] = Vector(List(0, 1, 2), List(0, 1, 3), List(0, 1, 4), List(0, 2, 3), List(0, 2, 4), List(0, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 4), List(1, 3, 4), List(2, 3, 4))
>
> scala> combinationsRecursiveLoop(5, 3).map("("+_.mkString(", ")+")").mkString(" ")
>
> res1: String = (0, 1, 2) (0, 1, 3) (0, 1, 4) (0, 2, 3) (0, 2, 4) (0, 3, 4) (1, 2, 3) (1, 2, 4) (1, 3, 4) (2, 3, 4)

It just provides all *r*-element subsets of the set of integers starting at zero containing *n* elements.  [More information on combinations can be found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Comment: Can you add some example of a client code calling your function and expected output? It's not clear, to me, what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think those recursive functions are pretty much the "standard" way of doing such a thing.

Comment: Very interesting question but I think recursion is usually the answer to nested, repeated behavior. I really hope to be proven wrong!

Comment: This construct is (was) known as a [power loop](http://wiki.c2.com/?PowerLoops), btw :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one way to look at this, that I have come up with.

You can extract one stage in your chain as a function `f: List[Int] => List[List[Int]]`, that takes a `List` with a beginning of a combination, and prepends all possible next elements to it.

For example in `choose(5, 3)`, `f(List(2, 0))` would result in `List(List(3, 2, 0), List(4, 2, 0))`.

Here is a possible implementation of such a function with some processing for the initial case added:

```
val f: List[Int] => List[List[Int]] = l =>
  (l.headOption.map(_ + 1).getOrElse(0) to n - (r - l.size))
    .map(_ :: l).toList
```

Now, such a function is a [Kleisli arrow](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html) `Kleisli[List, List[Int], List[Int]]`, and it's endomorphic (has the same argument and return types).

There is a [monoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40370767/1098230) instance for endomorphic kleisli arrows, where the monoid "addition" means the `flatMap` operation (or in pseudocode, `f1 |+| f2 == a => f1(a).flatMap(f2)`). So to replace your chain of `flatMap`s you need to "add" `r` instances of this `f` function, or in other words to multiply the `f` function by `r`.

This idea translates directly into Scalaz code:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def choose(n: Int, r: Int) = {
  val f: List[Int] => List[List[Int]] = l =>
    (l.headOption.map(_ + 1).getOrElse(0) to n - (r - l.size))
      .map(_ :: l).toList
  Endomorphic.endoKleisli(f).multiply(r).run(Nil)
}
```

And here is an example running it:

```
scala> choose(4, 3)
res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 1, 0), List(3, 1, 0), List(3, 2, 0), List(3, 2, 1))
```

The combinations are reversed, but it should be possible to make a version, that produces combinations with elements in the increasing order (or just run `choose(n, r).map(_.reverse)`).

Another improvement would be to make a lazy version, that returns `Stream[List[Int]]` (or even better a `scalaz.EphemeralStream[List[Int]]`: you don't want to have all the combinations cached in memory), but this is left as an exercise to the reader.